# Firefox crashes when selected running Lubuntu every time

Tags: lubuntu

I have an old HP Pavilion a720n which will run Ubuntu 16.04 but of course slowly due to the 1 GB memory on board. It WILL connect via Firefox to the internet with no issues.
I wanted to use a lighter version of Ubuntu to allow this old computer to run a little faster so I loaded Lubuntu ( most recent )  and Firefox crashes as soon as it is selected to go onto the internet. I have run the built in "check program" files and it finds no errors. 
Is there a fix for this or should I try a different version of Ubuntu to make the computer run a little faster?

Comment: You haven't told us what release of Lubuntu you are using, though I'm also wondering about the cpu in your system.  I tested Lubuntu (& Xubuntu) using 1gb systems, but know `firefox` has cpu requirements (eg. SSE2) that your machine may not provide (I mostly tested with intel cpu systems).  Does your cpu provide the requirements for `firefox` (eg. https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/62.0/system-requirements/ but check against your unspecified version) & what is your release of Lubuntu?

Comment: How about you try a lighter browser first. Like Midori `sudo apt install midori`

Comment: @Parto I wouldn't suggest midori if using a Qt based (Lubuntu 18.10 up) as the libs required will chew up any low-footprint as they won't be in memory. Without knowing the release (and thus using LXDE or LXQt) we can't know if a lighter GTK+ or Qt browser will help in my opinion.  The most recent 18.10 runs LXQt, however the [older but] most recent LTS runs LXDE.  Rapidrob if using the most recent 18.10 `falkon` is the lighter alternative  (it was replaced with firefox due to issues with some nvidia cards)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, I lost a close friend yesterday and it's been a little hectic. I found the SATA hard drive failed and would no longer boot. I'm reformatting it now and will down load Ubuntu Lite and give it a try as recommended. Since I'm starting from scratch again I'm open to any helpful suggestions you may add to allow this "new" software to work properly. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: OK I down loaded  three new "lite" Linux OS's to try.Linux Lite 3.8, Bohdi 5.0.0 Legacy, and Xenialpup 7.5 vefi. None will connect through Firefox and crash after 10 seconds or so. The Bohdi shows connection for Midori . They just crash Firefox after attempting to get onto the inter net. And as stated above, if I plug in the Unintu 16.04 hard drive Firefox connects in a normal way,just very slow due to my computers lack of memory. I'm stumped. Something is amiss but I'm not sure what ? I checked the F1 start up in the bois and can find nothing wrong. Midori never sees the wireless connection.

Comment: this site wont allow me to give all the details as they are too long.

Comment: Inputting the IP address and MAC did not help.